# How to add custom custom product filter in vue-storefront

Tags: vue.js, storefront, vue-storefront

I have a question: how to implement additional filter to the [vue-storefront](https://www.vuestorefront.io/) product items filters?

There are 4 filters (colors, Erin Recommends, price, size) in the default category sidebar and I want to add my custom filter, for example "brand", but I have no idea how to do this. There are nothing  useful I could find in the internet, this is official [documentation](https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/basics/recipes.html#adding-custom-category-filters), but this is not enough.

Can someone provide the manual or some documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have new attribute in your product inside Elasticsearcj - e.g. `brand`.
2. Inside your `config/local.json` in `products.defaultFilters` add `"brand"`.

Then after rerun app, you should see new filter on your category's view. Labels for this filter should be automatically fetched thanks to core/pages/Category.js -> asyncData and `attribute/list` action.