# Vue Storefront: Display labels for custom attribute filter instead of option id

Tags: vue.js, vuex, magento2, vue-storefront

I am trying to figure out from couple of days how to display label for filters on category page. As mentioned in document I have added attribute inside `config.products.defaultFilters[]` and the filter have started showing there.

I have `color` and `brand` filters. For color filters I have mapped color id to color name in `config.products.colorMappings` so it is displaying correctly there. But for brand I can do the same but it is a static solution so every time admin adds new brand I will need to add its mapping and build the storefront again.

I have tried to check their forum but nothing useful. I checked Vue Storefront vuex `catalog` and `category-next` stores for hint but cannot find anything related there.

[image]

The label for option under brand_filter should be readable but it is showing that brand attribute option's `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after spending couple of days finding solution to this problem, I finally got a hint from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117564/1929511).

I am using theme [vsf-capybara](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vsf-capybara), and according to its guide, to setup I generated a `local.json` from `generate-local-config.js` and I merged configuration manually from that `local.json` to `config/local.json` file. Prior to this there was no filter named brand or color added already to the main config file.

The config property responsible for the filter labels to be incorrect was `entities.attribute.loadByAttributeMetadata` and it was set to `true` I changed it to false because `core/module/catalog/CatalogModule` has one action `attribute/list` needs to be dispatched for application use. So if `entities.attribute.loadByAttributeMetadata` in `config/local.json` is set to true, this action will not be dispatched. Here is the excerpt from CatalogModule:

```
if (!config.entities.attribute.loadByAttributeMetadata) {
    await store.dispatch('attribute/list', { // loading attributes for application use
      filterValues: uniq([...config.products.defaultFilters, ...config.entities.productListWithChildren.includeFields])
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the ticked answer is not working. But the solution was to change the value `entities.attribute.loadByAttributeMetadata` to `true` in the file `config/local.json`, not of the `vue-storefront`, but of the `vue-storefront-api` project.